# Microsoft Dynamics Crm Remove 1:n Relationship

Tags: .net, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a 1:n relationship, between an incident and 0 to many emails,  in the Microst crm and I'm trying to delete these relationship with the DisassociateEntitiesRequest Class, but I get these exception:

> Entity Relationship Incident_Emailsls is not a many-to-many entity relationship

So my Question is how to remove an 1:n relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DisassociateEntitiesRequest only works on many-to-many relationships. Like you said, you are trying to delete a 1:n link between an incident and email(s). You can do this one of two ways:

1. Delete the email (which has a link to an incident)
2. Update the email by removing the reference (regarding object id) to the incident

Here's a link that may prove useful for either option: [Sample: Create, retrieve, update, and delete records](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334754.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set incident look-up value to NULL on email entity.